# Change CSH shell keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, csh

I want to set Ctrl-w to delete the previous word in csh (as it does by default in bash).

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bindkey "^W" backward-delete-word
```

Comment: This may be an adequate solution, but it could be improved by explaining *how* and *why* this works